# Pass the data in prefill while calling Omniscript from LWC HTML

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, omnistudio

I am having one scenario where i need to pass record id from LWC to Omniscript.
I got the record Id in the track variable, but i am strugling to assign as the below at the place of abc.

```
<c-test-for-jate prefill='\{"ContextId":"abc","otherParam":"test"}' layout="lightning"></c-test-for-jate>

JS
@track rIdFromAccount;
    @api set recordId(value) {
        this._recordId = value;
        this.rIdFromAccount = value;
   }
    get recordId() {
        return this._recordId;
    }
```

Trying below to set the recordId dynamically.

```
 <c-test-for-jate prefill='\{"ContextId":"{rIdFromAccount}","otherParam":"test"}' layout="lightning"></c-test-for-jate>
```

Throwing the below error :Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'error')

When i am hardcoding the id salesforce is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically set the record ID in the prefill attribute, you should use JavaScript's string concatenation instead of directly embedding the variable in the template string.

Modify the code as follows:

JS:

```
@track rIdFromAccount;
@api set recordId(value) {
    this._recordId = value;
    this.rIdFromAccount = value;
}
get recordId() {
    return this._recordId;
}
```

HTML:

```
<c-test-for-jate prefill={getPrefillData} layout="lightning"></c-test-for-jate>
```

Now, in your JS file, create a method named getPrefillData that returns the prefill data as a string:

JS:

```
get getPrefillData() {
    return JSON.stringify({ ContextId: this.rIdFromAccount, otherParam: "test" });
}
```

In this updated code, we use the getPrefillData method to dynamically generate the prefill attribute value, which includes the record ID obtained from the rIdFromAccount variable.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue in one of the requirements. You need to set the record ID in the below format to pass it from LWC to embedded Omniscript.

<c-test-for-jate record-id={recordId} layout="lightning"</c-test-for-jate

where recordId is the id of the record which you want to pass to the omniscript.